# Loft would intersect itself

Tags: autodesk-fusion-360

I am following a tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_BWN03vzsQ&list=PLG3dw9wUfgXN0D4aLjnsw40v3wECrruym&index=1&t=1128s

I have two sketches perpendicular to each other and am trying to create a loft but am getting the following error message: 'The loft would intersect itself. [image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I'm really sorry but using CAD software is generally off-topic here.  You might want to try Engineering Stack Exchange.  They do have some Fusion 360 questions which have been answered there.  If you want you can flag your own question and ask the mods to migrate it there for you.

Comment: Hello Chris. Welcome to GDSE. Looks like you cross-posted your question on [3D printing also](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/loft-would-intersect-itself). Generally, asking across multiple sites is frowned upon, since a 'good' question has but a single topic, and is therefore only a good fit for one single site. If you think your question belongs on a different site in the network, just ask it to be migrated there.

Comment: Thanks @PieBie, I have removed the other post.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be sure without having your file, but seems like you try to loft 2 perpenicular surfaces - the yellow one and the blue one. If a half of the blue one happens to be above the yellow one and the rest happens to be below the yellow one, the whole idea is absurd. Impossible even to imagine. You should have 3 separate surfaces - the yellow one, that blue half which is above the yellow one and the half of the blue one below the yellow one.